# DNS/VPN Blockers

Tags: dns

Hi i have a vpn app detoxify to block porn which works well, but when i go to motels for work and travel the wifi wont work and then i have to change the DNS. When i change the DNS the VPN does not work and porn and other bad sites can be accessed.

I want to block porn and other sites forever where i can't change or amend anything within the DNS and the VPN is not doing this. Is their a DNS porn blocker which i could not amend but would still allow me access to the web. Could you pls advise what i can do to block porn and other harmful sites and not be able to amend.

Comment: If its on your phone, then you can always change or uninstall it.  I am still confused about what you are after.  Is it for your child ?

Comment: No for mac, i want to block porn and have an existing vpn but when you change dns to acess wifi at motels even with vpn porn sites can then be accessed. I want to block porn where i cant amend or change anything.